# Как объединить данные из нескольких строк в одну, через запятую в SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы. В первой таблице поля `type` и `name`, в другой `name` и `value`. Необходимо получить строки, сгруппированные по полю `name` с общей суммой значений `value` и значениями `type`, перечисленными через запятую. При этом значения type не должны повторятся.

Помогите написать SQL запрос, а то уже сил никаких нет. С объединением и суммой все просто, но вот строка через запятую никак не выходит.

---

Пример:

```
Таблица 1:
-----------------
Name    |Type
-----------------
Мишка   |Игрушка
Мишка   |Зверь
Енот    |Зверь

Таблица 2:
-----------------
Name    |Value
----------------
Мишка   |200
Енот    |100
Енот    |200


Ожидаемый результат:
-------------------------
Мишка |200|Зверь,Игрушка
Енот  |300|Зверь
```

Comment: Что у вас получилось, пока силы не закончились? Добавте запрос в вопрос.

Comment: Ну если в объединением и суммой проблем нет, то тогда видимо надо было бы просто просить как собрать значения через запятую для группы и тогда ... можно закрывать вопрос как ...

Comment: @Mike стало интересно, так просуммировать без подзапроса получится?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Думаю нет, сначала группируем одну из таблиц, потом доклеиваем к запросу вторую и опять группируем. Или отдельно группируем каждую из таблиц и джоиним подзапросы.

Comment: Что значит _при этом значения type не должны повторятся_? В результате не должно быть строк с одинаковым значением или в каждом из значений каждый type должен быть лишь один раз?

Comment: *строка через запятую никак не выходит* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Ищите в поиске GROUP_CONCAT

Answer (score 1):

```
select t2.name,
       max(t2.sum_val),
       GROUP_CONCAT(distinct t1.type) 
from   ( select t2.name, 
                sum(t2.value) as sum_Val  
         from   table2 t2
         group  by t2.name 
        ) as t2
inner  join table1 t1
on     t1.name = t2.name
group  by t2.name
```